# Solving a one-to-one problem in database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, erd

Sorry if this is obvious but I'm new to database design.

A customer must make a reservation before renting an item(s), he provides details up front such as dates of reservation, item type etc. The employee checks if item is available before allowing the customer to rent it. If available he enters item id, rental date, return date, etc into the system.

Am I correct in creating two tables for this? One for Reservations(which includes the proposed rental info.) and one for Rentals (Which includes actual rental info). And If so, wouldn't these have a one to one relationship? How could I get around this one to one relationship? Should I merge the two tables?

Comment: When designing a schema, sketch out the queries (`SELECT, UPDATE`, etc) that will be used.  This usually help you find flaws in the schema and awkward places.

Comment: I frown on 1:1 relationships.  However, there are reasonable arguments for it in this case (see Implaler's Answer).  Flip a coin.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, since a reservation may never materialize as a rental, the relationship is not exactly 1:1 but 1:(0-1).

I would think that it's correct that you model them as separate entities since:

- They may have different "life cycles".
- They most likely have different properties.
- A rental will probably be related to a bunch of other entities compared to a reservation. Those FKs will make sense for rentals but not for reservations.

Comment: Could I potentially have a thing like this: 'Customer' has one to many with  'Item reservations'. And 'Item reservations' has many to one with 'Rentals'

Comment: @Liam I don't think there should be reservations N:1 against rentals. That doesn't look like what you described before. Anyway, in the end it's up to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but from what i'm understanding you can have just 1 table for rentals and have a column named `status` as enum (0,1) 0 being available and 1 rented. I'm assuming you are not renting the same item at the same time.

Comment: Hmmm, but I also have to record the reservation data? Like customer ID, requested rent date and requested return date, would it not get too clunky having all future reservation data in the rentals table?

Comment: Maybe i'm oversimplifying but you can have 3 tables, 1 for client, 1 for item and 1 for rental that has clienteId and itemId as FK and the rental table also has the reservation date and status